# Android Camera Saving Internally

Tags: android, image, save, capture

My problem is the following one, I need to save a picture of my camera application into the gallery so far couldnt achieve it, any guess where is wrong? Only posting the most importants parts... Help me, please!

> When the take picture button is pressed

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {      
private Camera mCamera;     
private CameraPreview mPreview;    
private String TAG = "CameraActivity";
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

@Override     
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);          

    // Create an instance of Camera  
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();          

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.         
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);         
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);         
    preview.addView(mPreview);     

    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mCamera.startPreview();
             //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
             mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
         }
    });
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;     
    try {         
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance     
    }     
    catch (Exception e){         
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)     
    }     return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable }
}


private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = new File(dir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

> Finding the path to save internally

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {      
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;     
private Camera mCamera;     

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {         
    super(context);         
    mCamera = camera;          

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the         
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.         
    mHolder = getHolder();         
    mHolder.addCallback(this);         
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0         
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);     
}      

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {         
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.         
    try {             
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);             
        mCamera.startPreview();         
    } catch (IOException e) {             
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());         
    }     
}      

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {   
    mCamera.release();
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.     
}      
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {         
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.         
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.          
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){           
        // preview surface does not exist           
        return;         
    }          

    // stop preview before making changes         
    try {             
        //mCamera.stopPreview();         
    } catch (Exception e){           
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview         
    }          
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or      
    // reformatting changes here          

    // start preview with new settings         
    try {             
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);             
        mCamera.startPreview();      
    } catch (Exception e){             
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());         
    }  
}
```

}

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
mCamera.StartPreview();
```

before the

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

**EDIT:** Also, instead of

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

use

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, mPicture);
```

If that does not work, try calling with

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new PictureCallBack());
```

Comment: I think there are more thing to change, only that was not enough.

Comment: I think that the getOutputMediaFile return the path to the gallery with the file name correct.

Comment: mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture); is okay